# Can I pass object from subclass to abstract class?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

This is my abstract class AbstractVehicles which implements Vehicles interface

```
public abstract class AbstractVehicles implements Vehicles{

}
```

and here's my CarImpl

```
public class CarImpl extends AbstractVehicles implements Car {
    private CarAI ai;
    private static final int CAR_FUEL_LEFT = 10;
    public CarImpl(){
        super(FUEL_LEFT);
        this.ai = new CarAI();
    }        
    public void move(World w){
        // AI is using here
        ai.act(w);
    }
}
```

and here's my BicycleImpl

```
public class BicycleImpl extends AbstractVehicles implements Bicycle {
    private BicycleAI ai;
    private static final int BICYCLE_FUEL_LEFT = 10;
    public BicycleImpl(){
        super(BICYCLE_FUEL_LEFT);
        this.ai = new BicycleAI();
    }        
    public void move(World w){
        // AI is using here
        ai.act(w);
    }
}
```

where interface of Car and Bicycle are marker Interface that

```
public interface Car extends Vehicles {
}


public interface Bicycle extends Vehicles {
}
```

The question come here
I have implemented an AI for car and Bicycle individually in other packages
called BicycleAI and CarAI. But there code in their CarImpl and BicycleImpl are the same. 
So I would Like to add that into the abstract class, so that code can be reused. 
And class BicycleAI and class CarAI is implementing interface AI.

As we can see above, their code for act is the same, but there AI objects are different. 
Is there anyway I can put this code into the abstract class?

I tried to do this

```
public abstract class AbstractVehicles implements Vehicles{
    protected AI ai;
    private int fuelLeft;
    public AbstractVehicles(int fuelLeft){
        this.fuleLeft = fuelLeft
        AI ai = new AI();
    }
    public void move(World w){
        ai.act(w); // But I have no idea this is CarAI or BicycleAI
    }
}
```

I am a bit confused about the constructor in AbstractVehicles and constructor in RabbitImpl. 
If I create an object RabbitImpl, and I call the move.

Comment: You can actually just put move in AbstractVehicles. Abstract classes can have concrete methods.

Comment: So, whats going wrong with what you tried?

Comment: Does your `CarAI` or `BicycleAI` a subclass of `AI`?

Comment: So, if I create a RabbitImpl Object, and I call move, it will run the code move in abstract class? but I also defined a constructor AI in Abstract vehicles. Is that appropriate?

Comment: CarAI and BycycleAI implments AI. and AI is an interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the **Template Method** pattern where the Super class defers certain steps to its Sub classes through the use of *abstract* methods. The step that you would delegate to your child classes here is to provide the actual `AI` implementation to be used by the rest of the parent *abstract* class code that you want the child classes to share.

```
public abstract class AbstractVehicles implements Vehicles{
    protected AI ai;

    public AbstractVehicles(){
        AI ai = initAI();
    }

    protected abstract AI initAI(); // template method

    public void move(World w){
        ai.act(w); // But I have no idea this is CarAI or BicycleAI
    }
}
```

Now, your `Car` and `Bicycle` classes would provide the template implementation as

```
public class CarImpl extends AbstractVehicles implements Car {

    protected AI initAI() {
        return new CarAI();
    }
}

public class BicycleImpl extends AbstractVehicles implements Car {

    protected AI initAI() {
        return new BicycleAI();
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, this is considered VERY BAD practice. You should NEVER call a non-final method from a constructor. This is even worse if the method being called in abstract. This is because the method is invoked in a class whose constructor has not completed. If the overriding method depends on any fields initialized in the constructor it will likely fail.

Comment: @JohnB, the sole purpose of the override is to provide an instance here. It has no dependency on what state the object currently is in.

Comment: Whatever the reason, it is VERY BAD practice to call a non-final method from a constructor (especially a method that is known to be overridden). It is not a pattern that should be given as an example of what to do. Given the question asked it is much better to pass in the instance to the constructor.

Comment: @JohnB, No, WHATEVER is not the reason! The method can't be *abstract* and *final* at the same time and is **not** expected to do anything else at all but instantiate the requisite implementation. Containers like Spring instantiate an unready bean all the time and then inject its dependencies through setters to make it complete. Frameworks issue callbacks all the time to get an instance they don't know the type of; the constructor is doing the same here. So, unless you provide a good reasoning with where the approach might break; well typing in CAPS isn't contributing much to the discussion.

Comment: https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/MET05-J.+Ensure+that+constructors+do+not+call+overridable+methods

Comment: http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#UR_UNINIT_READ_CALLED_FROM_SUPER_CONSTRUCTOR

Comment: @JohnB, It **does not apply** because the method **does not** perform a read op on any uninitialized field. It simply injects a dependency.

Answer (score 2):

Pass the `AI` to the abstract class' constructor.

```
 public abstract class AbstractVehicles implements Vehicles{
   protected final AI ai;
   public AbstractVehicles(AI ai){
      this.ai = ai;
   }
   public void move(World w){
     ai.act(w);
   }
}

public class CarImpl extends AbstractVehicles implements Car {
   public CarImpl(){
      super(new CarAI());
   } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But when I do this they need my ai in AbstractVehicles cast back to CarAI first?

Comment: In the future, please do not edit an answer in order to ask a question about it.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of templates in addition to your Abstract AI to make it know specifics

```
public abstract class AbstractVehicles<AI extends AbstractAI> implements Vehicles {
    protected AI ai;

    public AbstractVehicles(AI ai){
        this.ai = ai;
    }

    public void move(World w){
        ai.move(w);
    }
}
```

Of course the flaw to this design is you can't exactly take a generic class and construct it within your abstract class.  However you can do this just fine for sub classes

```
public abstract class CarImpl extends AbstractVehicles<CarAI> implements Car{

    public CarImpl(){
        super(new CarAI());
    }
}
```

By doing this, all AI references within CarImpl will identify as CarAI thanks to generic typing.

Answer (score 0):

[this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html) refers to the concrete class. So `this.ai` or `ai` is a reference to the actual implementation class field.